# How to format an elapsed time into minutes seconds and millis

Tags: android, kotlin

I have this:

```
collect { time ->
    text_view.text = DateUtils.formatElapsedTime(time)
}
```

But that gives me the minutes and seconds. What I need is

`%d:%d:%d`

*04:21:20*
minutes:seconds:milliseconds

The point of my question is not retrieving the time but formatting it.

Answer (score -1):

its Works fine for me and it will also Help You

```
        time_in_milli_seconds = p0
        var diff = time_in_milli_seconds
        val secondsInMilli: Long = 1000
        val minutesInMilli = secondsInMilli * 60
        val hoursInMilli = minutesInMilli * 60
        val daysInMilli = hoursInMilli * 24

        val elapsedDays = diff / daysInMilli
        diff %= daysInMilli

        val elapsedHours = diff / hoursInMilli
        diff %= hoursInMilli

        val elapsedMinutes = diff / minutesInMilli
        diff %= minutesInMilli

        val elapsedSeconds = diff / secondsInMilli

        yourTextView.setText(String.format("%02d", elapsedHours) + ":" + String.format("%02d", elapsedMinutes) + ":" + String.format("%02d", elapsedSeconds))
```